# laravel ReflectionException Class Country does not exist

Tags: php, laravel-5, homestead, laravel-artisan

I've read other issues about "ReflectionException Class ClassName does not exist" which refers to database seeders. I tried solutions from these questions and they didn't solve problem.

I've run into problem when tried to create model with command
`php artisan make:model Country`
(I've already had countries table)

after that I constantly get error

```
vagrant@homestead:~/Code/l53$ php artisan
```

> [ReflectionException]
>    Class Country does not exist

What I did after that:

1. created Country model manually
   http://joxi.ru/YmEyoL7CVNL0m6
2. added path to classmap
   http://joxi.ru/J2b4QvLc1dMgr6
3. run:

   ```
   composer update --no-scripts
   composer dump-autoload -o
   sudo composer self-update
   ```
4. deleted bootstrap/cache/services.php (there was only this file)

After every of these steps after running 'php artisan' I still receive:

> [ReflectionException]
>   Class Country does not exist

and after running `composer update` I receive:

> vagrant@homestead:~/Code/l53$ composer update
>   
> Loading composer repositories with package information
>   
> Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
>   
> Nothing to install or update
>   
> Generating autoload files
>   
> Illuminate\Foundation\ComposerScripts::postUpdate

```
php artisan optimize
```

> [ReflectionException]
>     Class Country does not exist

Script php artisan optimize handling the post-update-cmd event returned with error code 1

Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

P.S. I use laravel 5.3 via homestead

Comment: I tried solutions from that question and results you can see in my question

Answer (score 0):

I tried to remove vendor folder and 'composer update' (which recreated it) which didn't help.
but after 'vagrant reload' it (php artisan) worked... strange issue)